# Function maximized by $\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, maxima-minima, binomial-theorem

I was trying to maximize the function
$$f(r)=\binom nr\cdot 2^{n-r}$$
This can be done by the standard technique of looking at $\frac {f(r)}{f(r+1)}$ and the answer we get is that $r=\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor$ if $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$, and $r=\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}3\right\rfloor$ if $n=3k+2$. So, we can also say that the *maximizing set* of $f(r)=\binom nr\cdot 2^{n-r}$ is the set $\mathcal M_2=\left\{\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}3\right\rfloor\right\}$. Note that this set is irrespective of the modulo class of $n$ (as $\mathcal M_2=\{k,k\}=\{k\}$if $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$).

I was trying to play with this idea and figured out that if for some $p\in \mathbb N$, we define
$$f(r)=\binom nr\cdot (p-1)^{n-r}$$
then the *maximizing set* is $\mathcal M_{p-1}=\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor\right\}$.

I tried to play a little bit more with the *maximizing set* and started thinking about the set
$$\mathcal M=\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor, \dots ,\left\lfloor\frac {n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}$$
where $0\leq j\leq p$. Note that $\mathcal M$ still has only atmost $2$ elements since if $n=pk+i$, then
$$\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor, \dots ,\left\lfloor\frac {n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}=\{k\}\text{  if }i<j$$
$$\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor, \dots ,\left\lfloor\frac {n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}=\{k,k+1\}\text{  if }i\geq j$$

My question is, **is there any combinatorial function that is maximized by $\mathcal M$**? In other words, is there any combinatorial function $f_n(r)$ whose *maximizing set* is $\mathcal M$? I tried to construct some multinomials, but couldn't proceed much. I would like to have some help.

**Edit**: Since mutinomials didn't help, I was thinking in terms of graphs. If we consider a graph of a binomial, it has the typical binomial structure. What we are trying to achieve is to shift the maxima of that structure accordingly as $j$. So, it may happen that the function we are looking for is the binomial multiplied with some constant. Intuitively, we may even guess that this constant will be a box function involving $j$ somehow in it. But, I couldn't make any more out of this idea. See if it helps.

[Here's](https://mathoverflow.net/q/413571/311366) this post in MathOverflow.